# Image sensor initialisation sequence

Tags: image, sensors

Currently I am working in ev76c661 image sensor 
I need to how to switch image sensor from standby to ideal mode and pls share the initialisation sequence

Comment: I write the value on reg cntrl register 0x0004,to existing stand by state ,after that i read the value from sensor feedback register it's show image sensor in standby stand so have doubt about my and procedure and any one know the procedure means share immediately

Comment: I need to capture the image